# Image goes to black after resize it in client side - jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am using jQuery-File-Upload as an uploader, and when I enabled the image resizer, Some users get black images.

So when they select the image (preview image) it's fine, but when they click on confirm to start upload the image, the result is black image and this is happened on mobile devices with Chrome browser

This is how I initialized the plugin on my page:

```
jQuery(function () {
'use strict';
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
jQuery('#formular').fileupload({
// Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
//xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
url: '/upload_image.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    previewMaxWidth: 180,
    previewMaxHeight: 135,
    autoUpload: false,
    maxFileSize: 73400320,  
    loadImageMaxFileSize: 73400320,
    imageMaxWidth: 640,
    imageMaxHeight: 480,
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
process: [
        {
        action: 'load',
        fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png|jpg)$/,
        maxFileSize: 73400320
        },
        {
        action: 'resize',
        maxWidth: 640,
        maxHeight: 480
        },
        {
        action: 'save'
        }
    ],

    sequentialUploads: true,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    singleFileUploads: true,    
    submit: function(e ,data){
            data.formData = [{
                                    "name" : "action",
                                    "value" : "upload_image",
                            },
                            {
                                    "name" : "current_instance",
                                    "value" : CURRENT_INSTANCE
                            },
                            {       "name" : "category_id",
                                    "value" : jQuery('#category_group').val()
                            },
            {
                "name" : "image_rotate_value",
                "value" : jQuery('#image_rotate_value').val()
            }
            ];
    }
});

// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
jQuery('#formular').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
);
});
```

Anyone experience this before?

I searched about it and I found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No, I am not sure why I got this issue, but it seems to be from the manufacturer of some phones, These are the user agents which got black images: 

1- Lenovo A850+  Lenovo_A850+
2- HM NOTE 1W
3- Lenovo S939 
4- HUAWEI G750-U10
5- Coolpad 8297W 
6- vivo X3S 
7- Coolpad 7320

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer or something else, maybe to reproduce this issue ?